# Jump through html5 video player

Tags: html5-video

I have a html5 video player and I want to play from a specific time (e.g 6:10 to 6:20) and after that to start again from 6:10, which is fine for me, but when I'm trying to set manually to start from another time different from 6:10, I cannot do that...it jump to 6:10.

```
var videoPlayer = document.createElement('video');
var videoStartTime = 0;
var durationTime = 0;

videoPlayer.src = video.src;
videoPlayer.id = "videoPlayer";
videoPlayer.setAttribute('autoplay',true);
videoPlayer.setAttribute('controls',true);

videoPlayer.addEventListener('play', function() {
    videoStartTime = time;
    durationTime = 10;
    videoPlayer.currentTime = videoStartTime;
}, false);

videoPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if(videoPlayer.currentTime > videoStartTime + durationTime){
        videoPlayer.currentTime = videoStartTime;
    }
});
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. What file do you use - mp4? Which browser? Does seeking manually using the UI controls work?

Comment: I used .mp4 videos, browser: firefox, chrome, I have only the play/pause control

Comment: Don't you have a seek bar? Maybe your .mp4 file is not seekable. Test with a good, known to work file like this one: http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-85.mp4

Comment: I have a seek bar, but I cannot seek it manually, when I am trying to do that it start from currentTime that I set from the code (videoPlayer.currentTime = videoStartTime;) If I remove from the code the line where  I set currentTime, I can seek time manually